# Find when picker view selection changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipickerview

Is there any way I can have an object receive a message when the user changes the selected row in the picker view? My pickerview has two components and it is dismissed when the user taps the screen once. But I need to gray out certain options in the second component depending on which option in the first component is chosen.

One other option is to use a timed function to periodically check which row is selected, but that's really hacky. Are there any delegate functions I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPickerView has a delegate that you can use, called UIPickerViewDelegate. In it, there is a method called:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

That lets you know what row they've selected and in what component, and should accomplish what you're asking, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Ah, I missed that in the documentation somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`.

`row` tells you what row it is and `component` tells you which component it's in.

Remember to include `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent
```

It's one of UIPickerView's delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [`UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html)

Especially the message might be interesting to you:

> pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
>   Called by the picker view when the user selects a row in a component.